# SQL Server: problems with max and IN clause

Tags: sql-server

I have this table in SQL Server 2008:

```
create table [hFUNDASSET] 
(
    [hFundAssetID] numeric(19,0) identity not null, 
    [fundAssetID] numeric(19,0) not null, 
    [modified] datetime not null, 
    primary key ([hFundAssetID])
);
```

Its a history table, the goal is to get the closest `hFundAssetID` based on a given max `modified` column timestamp, for every distinct `fundAssetID`.

The following query gets the correct latest `modified` for each `fundAssetID`:

```
select max(modified), fundAssetID 
    from hFundAsset 
 where fundAssetID IN 
    (
        select distinct (fundAssetID) 
            from hFundAsset where modified < 'April 20, 2010 11:13:00'
    )
group by fundAssetID;
```

I can't put the `hFundAssetID` in the select clause without it being in the `group by` , which would return extra rows. Somehow, I need the `hFundAssetID` matching each one of the `modified, fundAssetID` pairs returned in the above query, or equivalent. But SQL Server doesn't allow multiple values for the IN clause, according to their docs:

"subquery - Is a subquery that has a result set of one column. 
           This column must have the same data type as test_expression."

Googling shows that 'exists' and joins are typically used with mssql in these cases, but I've tried that using 'max' and 'group by' and I'm having problems getting it to work. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT a.*,
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY fundAssetID ORDER BY modified DESC) rnk
        FROM hFundAsset a
     WHERE modified < 'April 20, 2010 11:13:00' 
)   
SELECT *
  FROM qry
WHERE rnk = 1
```

Comment: Nice use of RANK().  I was very happy when 2005 added that.

Comment: It might be worth it to note, if your data happens to have multiple rows with the exact same modified date and fundAssetID, you could end up with multiple rows in your result with the same fundAssestID but different hFundAssestID's.  If that is not desired, you could use ROW_NUMBER() instead.  Good answer though.

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your quick and helpful response! It'll take me some time to understand it, but I certainly have learned a lot :-) . EDIT: I'll look at the ROW_NUMBER suggestion during our testing, thanks.